# Getting Error when try to use where clause before LEFT JOINS tables

Tags: sql

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Resv_LoadResv]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        rs.[Id] AS 'Id',
        bkngSrc.[SourceName] AS 'BkngSrc',
        payMode.[Description] AS 'PayMode',
        rs.[GuestName] AS 'GuestName',
        rs.[Addr] AS 'Addr',
        rs.[City] AS 'City',
        rs.[EntryDate] AS 'EntryDate'
    FROM 
        dbo.ResvReg rs
    -- when I try to put where clause here, I get an error
    WHERE 
        EntryDate >= '11/08/2018'
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].[BkngSource] bkngSrc ON rs.[BkngSrc] = bkngSrc.[Id]
    LEFT JOIN 
        [dbo].[PaymentMode] payMode ON rs.[PayMode] = payMode.[Id]
END
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct.  `LEFT JOIN` is an operator that works in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a SQL clause that follows the `FROM` clause.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Put the `WHERE` after the `JOIN`s, just before the `END`.

Comment: You put `WHERE` at the wrong place.

Comment: Sidenotes: It's a bad idea to compare a date column with the string '11/08/2018' and have the DBMS find out whether that is November 8 or August 11. Then, single quotes are string delimiters. If your DBMS allows you to use them for names, you still shouldn't do that, as that's prone to errors. Then, why do you use brackets for the names? You don't need them. At last: qualify all your columns, i.e. `WHERE rs.EntryDate >= …`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because syntax is wrong. Where clause filters the records so typically it is used at the end of the query like

```
 SELECT 
    rs.[Id]         AS 'Id'
    ,bkngSrc.[SourceName]    AS 'BkngSrc'
    ,payMode.[Description]   AS 'PayMode'
    ,rs.[GuestName]          AS 'GuestName'
    ,rs.[Addr]               AS 'Addr'
    ,rs.[City]               AS 'City'
    ,rs.[EntryDate]          AS 'EntryDate'
FROM dbo.ResvReg rs
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[BkngSource] bkngSrc on rs.[BkngSrc] = bkngSrc.[Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PaymentMode] payMode on rs.[PayMode] = payMode.[Id]
WHERE EntryDate>= '11/08/2018'
```

If you want to filter first and then join you have use write a nested query. Something like this will do the trick

```
SELECT 
        t.[Id]         AS 'Id'
        ,bkngSrc.[SourceName]    AS 'BkngSrc'
        ,payMode.[Description]   AS 'PayMode'
        ,t.[GuestName]          AS 'GuestName'
        ,t.[Addr]               AS 'Addr'
        ,t.[City]               AS 'City'
        ,t.[EntryDate]          AS 'EntryDate'
from
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.ResvReg rs
    WHERE EntryDate>= '11/08/2018'
) t
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[BkngSource] bkngSrc on t.[BkngSrc] = bkngSrc.[Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PaymentMode] payMode on t.[PayMode] = payMode.[Id]
```